# Is special relativity committed to a violation of Occam’s razor?

Tags: special-relativity

Say I have two atomic clocks, perfectly in sync, in the same location on the equator of the earth. I put one of them in a jet and fly it around the equator. When I land, the jet clock that went on the voyage is behind the land clock that did not.

The way I understand SR, there is no sense in saying that the jet clock ‘really’ slowed down or the land clock ‘really’ sped up. We have a physical effect, the interpretation of which depends on which frame of reference you take to describe it.

But now if I ring the equator with one billion and one atomic clocks (all in sync) and do the same experiment, I get the same result. The jet clock is behind the billion land clocks.

It seems much more parsimonious in this case to say that the jet clock really slowed down, generating a physical effect in a single clock, because otherwise physical effects are being generated in a billion clocks simultaneously.

I understand that the question of how spacetime can couple to matter to induce these physical effects is an open question. In the absence of a resolution of this question, it seems to me that SR is committed to a violation of Occam’s razor.

Comment: [John D. Norton](https://www.hps.pitt.edu/people/john-d-norton) has written extensively on the history & philosophy of relativity, eg [Einstein for Everyone](http://www.pitt.edu/~jdnorton/teaching/HPS_0410/chapters/index.html).

Comment: I'd say a billion extraneous clocks are better candidates for a shave . . .

Comment: @m4r35n357 Sure, so instead make the jet clock a particle and make the billion clocks also particles. Same question.

Answer (score 3):

Neither clock physically speeds up or slows down. They have just traveled different distances in space-time.  Occam's razor never enters.

Comment: I understand that this is the standard answer, but I think that, deep down, it is a cop out. Nobody knows how matter couples to spacetime, or even what spacetime actually is. The characteristics of a Doppler-shifted sound wave also take a different path in acoustic spacetime than those described by the wave equation, but in that case the physical effects are understood. In this case we have real physical effects that are created in a mysterious way, and I don’t think it’s the right approach to pretend the mystery isn’t there because you can talk about Poincaré groups and Minkowski space.

Answer (score 1):

First, to make sense of your assumption that the billion-and-one clocks on the equator are "all in synch", let's treat the center of the earth as inertial (ignoring the motion of the earth around the sun) and assume that the clocks are all in synch according to an observer at the center of the earth.

Let's also have a billion-and-one jet planes, with clocks all in synch according to that same observer, flying around the equator, say in the same direction that the earth revolves.

Now that observer will say that the clocks on the billion-and-one jets all run slower than the clocks on the equator.  Where's the asymmetry?  We have a billion-and-one clocks traveling at one speed and running slow, and another billioon-and-one traveling at a faster speed and running slower.

Ah, you say --- but that's not your experiment.  In your experiment there was only *one* jet.

Yes, but surely whatever we say about the clock on that jet should be independent of whether there happen to be another billion jets flying the route at the same time.

In other words, any asymmetry in your story  results from your quite asymmetric initial choice to put a billion clocks on the equator but only one jet in the air.  You could have done the opposite, with one clock on the earth and a billion in the air.

Or (at the risk of belaboring this) I'll put it another way:

In experiment One, there are a billion clocks on earth and one on a jet.  According to you, Occam's razor says that we should say the jet clock is the one that changed its speed.

In experiment Two, there is one clock on earth and a billion on jets.  By the same reasoning, Occam's razor says that we should say the earth clock is the one that changed its speed.

But  the answer to whether a clock has changed its speed should be independent of whether it is one clock out of one or one clock out of a billion.  So your argument leads to madness.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, which allows me to clarify my question. In the set up, all clocks are initially in the same inertial frame. Speeding one clock up in a jet requires energy. The physical effect observed after the jet lands can be described from one of the two frames of reference. It seems to me more parsimonious to apply the physical effect to the clock that underwent the change in energy. But according to SR as I understand it, this is not allowed. The physical effect can be thought of as applying to all the land clocks, to which no change was applied.